# How to run a PCA or Factor Analysis when you know one column of the factor loadings

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

I have this application where I have a direction that I want to keep fixed when I'm running a PCA or factor analysis. Is this possible? I just want to keep a column of the loadings matrix fixed.

How can I do that?

If this is not possible. Can I do any other type of analysis with this direction?

Comment: Yes: project your matrix $\mathbf{A}$ along the unit direction $\mathbf{v}$ you want to keep, i.e. $\mathbf{A}_1 = (\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^\top)\mathbf{A}$, then do PCA on $\mathbf{A}_1$ per usual, but replace the zero eigenvalue now accompanying the direction $\mathbf{v}$ with $\mathbf{v}^\top\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v}$ at the end.

Comment: Nice. And I guess if I had 2 such directions that I want to preserve, I would just project on the plane generated by $v_1$ and $v_2$. Run PCA "per usual" and then replace the zero eigenvalues associated to the two directions with $v_1^TAv_1$ and $v_2^TAv_2$. Right?

Comment: Yes sounds good.

Comment: See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/473277/244807

Comment: @cdalitz thanks for this comment; looking at that post reminded me to emphasize: $\mathbf{A}$ has a datapoint in each *column* in my comment, so $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{X}^\top$ in my case. (If I'm not mistaken, your answer leaves out a detail as well :)).

Comment: I thought $A = \Sigma$ the covariance matrix. Can it also work that way?